# Weak convergence of sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of real-valued random variables such that their weak limit $X$ exists and is not constant almost surely. Furthermore, suppose that there exist a sequence of positive real numbers $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and a sequence of real numbers $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_n X_n + b_n$ converges weakly to another random variable $Y$. I want to show that in the above setting there exist $a\geq 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$. Moreover, if $Y$ is also not constant almost surely, then $a$ is supposed to be positive. I am grateful for any help!

Comment: Maybe you could use  characteristic functions here?

Comment: A keyword is "convergence of types".